# Files (from packagekit packages) disappeared on Fedora 28 Workstation

Tags: fedora

I had to reinstall PackageKit-glib2 because of errors about missing `libpackagekit-glib2.so.18`.  `rpm -q --verify` says there were a couple of files missing, and even after reinstalling that package, there are some other packages I need to reinstall

```
missing     /usr/lib64/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gtk-modules/pk-gtk-module.desktop
missing     /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/modules/libpk-gtk-module.so
missing     /usr/lib64/gtk-3.0/modules/libpk-gtk-module.so
missing   c /etc/PackageKit/CommandNotFound.conf
missing     /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh
missing     /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found
missing     /usr/libexec/pk-gstreamer-install
```

`rpm -q --verify --all` didn't find anything else either missing or corrupted.

I was quite surprised by this. Package updates replace files atomically using `rename()` (and should use `fsync()` before `rename()` to guarantee that the written contents are not lost in case power is interrupted).

Is there a bug in Fedora 28 which could have removed these files?

Or is it some other known issue, e.g. with hardware?

Is there a report of a similar symptom anywhere else?

---

The current date is 2018-05-28. `etckeeper` (which updates daily) suggests the files in `/etc` were lost by `2018-05-16 11:33:41`.

I can see an offline package update just before this, but the only package it admits to upgrading is `ostree`.

```
$ journalctl --since=-1month /usr/libexec/pk-offline-update
...
May 16 11:17:03 alan-laptop pk-offline-update[773]: package updating        ostree-2018.5-1.fc28.x86_64 (updates)
...
May 16 11:17:05 alan-laptop pk-offline-update[773]: package cleanup        ostree-2018.3-2.fc28.x86_64 (installed)
```

`dnf history` shows

```
   328 | install PackageKit       | 2018-05-16 11:33 | Install        |    1  <
   327 | debuginfo-install glibc- | 2018-05-16 11:02 | Update         |    2 > 
   326 | downgrade ostree         | 2018-05-16 10:56 | Downgrade      |    1  <
   325 | builddep PackageKit      | 2018-05-16 10:47 | Install        |   11 ><
```

---

GNOME Disks SMART information for my hard drive reports "Disk is OK", and the short SMART test succeeded with no errors.

`/lost+found/` is empty.

This system is an upgrade from Fedora 27 (etc), not a fresh install.

The hardware is a Dell Lattitude E5450 - a business series laptop - with a spinning hard drive.  The hard drive identifies as `WDC WD5000LPLX-75ZNTT0 (01.01A01)`.

### coredumpctl -r list /usr/libexec/packagekitd

I had some packagekit crashes two weeks before the files in /etc went missing: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1523706#c21

and according to coredumpctl, I had a couple of later crashes that were very close to the date the files went missing

```
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG COREFILE  EXE
Mon 2018-05-14 18:14:01 BST    4474     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Mon 2018-05-14 16:40:28 BST    1599     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Wed 2018-05-02 12:10:53 BST    2174     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Wed 2018-05-02 11:39:55 BST   27919     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Wed 2018-05-02 10:47:53 BST   25548     0     0   6 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Wed 2018-05-02 10:46:52 BST   21783     0     0   6 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Wed 2018-05-02 10:42:43 BST   18529     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Wed 2018-05-02 10:37:56 BST   12763     0     0   6 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Wed 2018-05-02 10:15:49 BST    1569     0     0   6 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Sat 2018-04-28 14:34:43 BST    1394     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Tue 2018-03-06 10:54:03 GMT    1498     0     0   6 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Wed 2018-02-28 10:40:55 GMT    1487     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Fri 2018-02-23 21:01:21 GMT    1557     0     0   6 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Thu 2017-11-16 10:05:46 GMT   10987     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Tue 2017-11-14 11:04:56 GMT    1631     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Mon 2017-10-16 16:56:48 BST    1557     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
Thu 2017-09-28 16:31:19 BST    1513     0     0  11 missing   /usr/libexec/packagekitd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    328 | install PackageKit       | 2018-05-16 11:33 | Install        |    1  <
>    327 | debuginfo-install glibc- | 2018-05-16 11:02 | Update         |    2 > 
>    326 | downgrade ostree         | 2018-05-16 10:56 | Downgrade      |    1  <
>    325 | builddep PackageKit      | 2018-05-16 10:47 | Install        |   11 ><
> ```

This problem was caused by some testing I did.

I removed PackageKit using `rpm --nodeps -e`, so I could build and install a [patched](https://github.com/hughsie/PackageKit/pull/251) PackageKit.

I then used `make uninstall`, and `dnf install PackageKit`.

The problem is that the PackageKit source package is split into several different RPMs.  So I had only reinstalled the main one, and not any of the sub-packages.